# pandas merge_asof: ambiguous argument types error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to use `merge_asof` from Pandas and I've been getting the error:

`TypeError: Function call with ambiguous argument types`

Reproducible example:

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.DataFrame({'foo': [1., 2.], 'bar': ['2019-01-01 00:00:10', '2019-01-01 00:00:20']})
b = pd.DataFrame({'foo': [2., 5.], 'baz': ['2019-01-01 00:00:05', '2019-01-01 00:00:25']})
a['bar'] = pd.to_datetime(a['bar'])
b['baz'] = pd.to_datetime(b['baz'])

pd.merge_asof(a,
              b,
              left_on='bar',
              right_on='baz',
              direction='backward',
              by='foo',
              allow_exact_matches=False)
```

I've tried to inspect the pandas.core.reshape.merge file but had no luck solving the problem

Comment: Seems to be an issue with the `by` being for a `float` column. I.e. it works with `[1, 2]` and `[2, 5]`. Since it's an *exact* match ideally those aren't floats, so probably best to store them as `int64` or if missing data `Int64`

Comment: that solves the problem, thanks!

Comment: I just came across this same error when trying to use `on` with `type() str` for dates.  Got the same ambiguous error.  However, when I converted them to pandas datetime objects (`pd.to_datetime()`) and tried the same exact code - it worked fine.

Comment: The type of the `on` column must by a `datetime` (not a `datetime.date`). The type of the `by` column must be a `int` (not a `float`).

Answer (score 4):

The "By" variable must not be float.

It can be "integer" or "string".

Answer (score 0):

Problem of
pd.merge_asof(
left,
right,
on=None,by=None) is due to "ON" parameter. It must be of date type otherwise it will throw error of ambiguous argument type.so we need to convert them to pandas datetime objects using pd.to_datetime() to solve the error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To add to @doraelee's answer,
not only does the 'by' column must be of type `int` and not `float`,
it also can't be `int32` (can be `int64`).

Now, I understand `float` can't be used in the `by` column, of course, but I can't understand why `int32` isn't valid; however this is the result I've found.

Example of failing code (pandas version=2.1.1), with a slight change to the MCVE provided in the question:

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.DataFrame({'foo': [1., 2.], 'bar': ['2019-01-01 00:00:10', '2019-01-01 00:00:20']})
b = pd.DataFrame({'foo': [2., 5.], 'baz': ['2019-01-01 00:00:05', '2019-01-01 00:00:25']})

a['bar'] = pd.to_datetime(a['bar'])
b['baz'] = pd.to_datetime(b['baz'])

a = a.astype(dict(foo=int)) # the whole thing will pass if we replace int with 'int64'
b = b.astype(dict(foo=int)) # here as well, of course

pd.merge_asof(a,
              b,
              left_on='bar',
              right_on='baz',
              direction='backward',
              by='foo',
              allow_exact_matches=False)
```

Comment: I run your "int32" code and nothing went wrong. My pandas version is 1.5.3. Maybe this issue happends in new version of pandas.

Comment: @Doraelee Thank you, can you try to reproduce the failure on a newer version? If it does not reproduce, I'll delete my answer.