# Merging based on the order of a specific value Pandas

Tags: pandas

Suppose I have two dataframes with the following values:

```
DF1  Name        Time-In
      Person1     2020-04-21 20:32:44
      Person2     2020-04-21 20:37:19
      Person3     2020-04-21 20:44:04
      Person1     2020-04-21 21:17:22
      Person1     2020-04-21 23:00:00


DF2   Name        Time-Out
      Person1     2020-04-21 20:50:11
      Person2     2020-04-21 21:15:15
      Person1     2020-04-21 22:00:59
```

I want to merge the tables based on the order in which Name appears (Person1's first Time-In on DF1 is merged to Person1's first Time-Out on DF2), and for NaN instances like Person3, who has no record in DF2, and for cases when Person1 has an extra value in DF1. The final table would look like this:

```
DF3   Name        Time-In                   Time-Out
      Person1     2020-04-21 20:32:44       2020-04-21 20:50:11
      Person2     2020-04-21 20:37:19       2020-04-21 21:15:15
      Person3     2020-04-21 20:44:04       NaN
      Person1     2020-04-21 21:17:22       2020-04-21 22:00:59
      Person1     2020-04-21 23:00:00       NaN
```

Any ideas as to how I can do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) with `direction='forward'` parameter:

```
df1['Time-In'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Time-In'])
df2['Time-Out'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Time-Out'])

df = pd.merge_asof(df1, 
                   df2, 
                   left_on='Time-In',
                   right_on='Time-Out', 
                   by='Name',
                   direction='forward')
print (df)
      Name             Time-In            Time-Out
0  Person1 2020-04-21 20:32:44 2020-04-21 20:50:11
1  Person2 2020-04-21 20:37:19 2020-04-21 21:15:15
2  Person3 2020-04-21 20:44:04                 NaT
3  Person1 2020-04-21 21:17:22 2020-04-21 22:00:59
4  Person1 2020-04-21 23:00:00                 NaT
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Apparently, it yields TypeError: Function call with ambiguous argument types. I have other columns aside from those two in df1, does that affect the code?

Comment: @EnigmaticCocoon - hmmm, can you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58402755/2901002) ? Is possible by with `float` column?

Comment: All of my other columns have the str data type.

Comment: @EnigmaticCocoon - so there are datetimes columns and all strings? what is `print (df1.dtypes)` and `print (df2.dtypes)` ?

Comment: It's okay now, had some mistakes in writing it. Thanks a lot!