# How to perform an asof merge between two DataFrames in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two DataFrames, `df1` and `df2`, and I would like to perform an asof merge using pandas' `merge_asof`. Both DataFrames have a column named "Frutas", and I want to combine information from the "Data" column (in `df1`) and the "Data/Hora" column (in `df2`) for the closest corresponding fruits.

The DataFrames have the following structure:

**DataFrame df1:**

```
datas_df1 = [datetime(2023, 8, 1), datetime(2023, 8, 3), datetime(2023, 8, 2), datetime(2023, 8, 1),

             datetime(2023, 8, 1), datetime(2023, 8, 3), datetime(2023, 8, 4), datetime(2023, 8, 4),

             datetime(2023, 8, 2), datetime(2023, 8, 4)]

 

df1_dict = {

    "Frutas": ["Maçã", "Banana", "Laranja", "Uva", "Morango", "Pera", "Abacaxi", "Melancia", "Cereja", "Kiwi"],

    "Data": datas_df1,

    "Transcricao": [f"Transcricao_{i}" for i in range(10)]

}

 

df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1_dict)
```

**DataFrame df2:**

```
datas_df2 = [datetime(2023, 8, 1, 14, 37), datetime(2023, 8, 3, 8, 23), datetime(2023, 8, 1, 9, 56),

             datetime(2023, 8, 4, 12, 9), datetime(2023, 8, 3, 10, 50), datetime(2023, 8, 2, 17, 38),

             datetime(2023, 8, 4, 19, 22), datetime(2023, 8, 2, 7, 44), datetime(2023, 8, 1, 21, 33),

             datetime(2023, 8, 2, 23, 6)]

 

df2_dict = {

    "Frutas": ["Maçã", "Banana", "Laranja", "Uva", "Morango", "Pera", "Abacaxi", "Melancia", "Cereja", "Kiwi"],

    "Data/Hora": datas_df2,

    "Pedido de venda": [f"Pedido_{i}" for i in range(10)]

}

 

df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2_dict)
```

I would like to perform an asof merge between these DataFrames based on the "Frutas" column, "Data" in `df1`, and "Data/Hora" in `df2`, so that each fruit is associated with the closest date/time, and thus include the "Transcricao" and "Pedido de venda" columns in the merged DataFrame.

How can I achieve this using pandas? Any help or examples to solve this problem would be greatly appreciated!

I tried to do an merge_asof, but I wasn't successful, I was probably making a mistake in the code

```
df_merge = pd.merge_asof(df1.sort_values('data'), 
                                   df2.sort_values('Data/Hora'), 
                                   left_on='data', 
                                   right_on='Data/Hora',
                                   by='Frutas')
```

I had the following error:
TypeError: Function call with ambiguous argument types

Comment: Do you have `NaN`s in `Frutas` column?

Comment: No, there is no NaN in the column Frutas

Comment: Maybe this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58402755/pandas-merge-asof-ambiguous-argument-types-error  Check other columns if you don't have floats or other types in your dataframe.

Comment: I'm not receiving any errors beyond the fact that `data` should be capitalized in your `merge_asof`

Answer (score 0):

You are good to go but you have to add direction in the `merge_asof` as direction is one of the argument of that function.

Here, I'm attaching the link of official documentation for your help [Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html).
You can send direction as "per your requirement.

Example:

```
df_merge = pd.merge_asof(df1.sort_values('Data'), df2.sort_values('Data/Hora'),
                         left_on='Data', right_on='Data/Hora', by='Frutas', direction='forward')
```

Also attached the output:
[image]